# react native enable hot reload/fast refresh for node_module java file

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, hot-reload

After `react-native run-android`, device was able to auto-refresh each time if I made change on my code.

But code in `node_module` behaved slightly different from what I expect. It still works perfectly on modifying the `js/tsx, etc file`, but change `java file` or `native module` wouldn't trigger any change unless I rerun `react-native run-android`.

Is this the default behavior or I miss something from my configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got answer from react community contributor, Fast reload only works for javascript file, native code need to be reinstall in order to update changes.